# How to align text value center in gridview column

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have gridview which is bind from the data coming from table how to show it's text value coming in column centrally aligned.
`GridView` as follows.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvPropertyData" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvPropertyData_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" SelectText="&lt;i class=&quot;fa fa-bar-chart&quot; aria-hidden=&quot;true&quot;&gt;&lt;/i&gt;" />
    </Columns>
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <div align="center">No records found.</div>
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:GridView>
```

On page load Data is being bind

```
gvPropertyData.DataSource = getDTFromQuery(query);
gvPropertyData.DataBind();
```

Answer (score -1):

First you should to add a cssClass to your GridView.
And then you can do it by adding the following css codes.

```
.gvPropertyData td, .gvPropertyData th{
  text-align:center;
}
```